# How to do a LIKE in Entity Framework CORE (not full .net)

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, sql-like

In the **Full .Net EF** LIKE's used to be `SqlMethods.Like`, eg:

```
from c in dc.Organization
where SqlMethods.Like(c.Boss, "%Jeremy%")
```

This doesn't work in **EF Core** and I get this error:

> The name SqlMethods does not exist in the current context.

So how do you do a LIKE using Entity Framework CORE?

Comment: @Ivan that has the same answer however it's only got 21 views, while this has 27 ATM. Poor choice for a closure. Reason ppl like this leave: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5/jon-galloway

Comment: Frankly I didn't look at such statistics. Duplicate is just (and still) duplicate :)

Comment: Better and more indexable than your duplicate, reverse it now please. The difference is `InStr` where as this is `CHARINDEX`, retagging SQL Server

Comment: @Ivan, c'mon, check my profile I'm someone who is donating good answers

Comment: I agree that this question is better formulated. But what to do with the other then? Mark it as duplicate of this? (I'll remove the closure, no problem)

Comment: Anyway, there you go. Cheers.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The LIKE function has moved under `EF.Functions` in Core:

```
from c in dc.Organization
where EF.Functions.Like(c.Boss, "%Jeremy%")
```

Answer (score 3):

Fluent version:

```
dc.Organization.Where(o => EF.Functions.Like(o.Boss, "%Jeremy%"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Like` function you can use `Contains`

```
from c in dc.Organization
where c.Boss.Contains("Jeremy")
```

Comment: No, if you run say SQL profiler to capture the raw SQL query you'll see `Contains` uses SQLs `CHARINDEX` Functions. `EF.Functions.Like` maps correctly to SQL `LIKE` in the query.

Comment: but when a huge amount of data is there then use CHARINDEX it's work faster then like

Comment: It's not the same, say for example when Full-Text Search is enabled.

Comment: Also when the search term is null, CHARINDEX returns nothing, while LIKE returns everything.

Comment: yeh! that's true

Comment: Contains can be used _in this example_ but in general it is much less than Like. Even MS SQL pattern matching is much more, e.g. "_________2___" is a like expression but not a Contains expression. (Okay, in this simple case you can use charindex.) It's not a theoretical thing, in Scala (a pretty old ERP) all ledger dimensions are merge into a big string and one must make filter by positional values.